# ADB error An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host error: protocol fault (couldn't read status): Connection reset by peer

Tags: android, adb, ota

Since yesterday I am getting the following error continuously in Android Studio 4.0.

```
13:06   Adb connection Error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

13:06   Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.

13:07   * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

13:07   * daemon started successfully
```

I get

```
adb connect 192.168.0.110
error: protocol fault (couldn't read status): Connection reset by peer
```

And continuously try to reconnect without succeding

I'm using adb.exe latest version (1.0.41)

I read a lot of questions here and all of the following methods did not work:

> adb kill-server

> adb start-server

I tried in cmd.exe and adb seems working fine. But I can't use adb without using android studio.
I am using adb over the air. Because RPI3 with Android things does not support USB connection. (I tried with my android phone and the error persists)

When I connect the phone I am getting this

> Unable to open connection to: localhost/127.0.0.1:5037, due to: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect